# How to implement Bootstrap select-picker plugin in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I'm new to programming. I want to implement **bootstrap selectpicker** to my MVC 5 project. But I don`t know how to implement plugins to the project. Could you please explain how to implement plugin to MVC 5 application?

I`m using Visual Studio 2018 community edition. I installed bootstrap selectpicker via NuGet package manager.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Suppliers", new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.Suppliers, "SupplierID", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control selectpicker" })
```

I need a multi-select drop-down list but now I have just a simple dropdown list.

Comment: Do you mean how to use Bootstrap select plugin?